# Simple balance incomplete block design, (complete graph clique decomposition)

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to find methods to construct a $(n,k,1)$-BIBD with large $n$ and $k$.

Basically, I'm wondering if there's an established method to create as many sets of size $k$ from elements $\{1, ..., n\}$ such that no pair of sets share any pair of elements (in other words, no sets have an intersection greater than one).

This problem can also be modeled as edge decomposition of a complete graph of size $n$ into cliques of size $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topic of constructing $2-(n,k,1)$-designs is a large field. Suffices to mention e.g. [Steiner triple systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Steiner_triple_systems) (the case $k=3$), [affine planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Affine_planes) (the case $n=k^2$), etc.

There are hundreds of different methods, working for particular cases, but no general method. For most values of parameters there is no complete answer known - Steiner triple systems (STS) are more of an exception, where a simple numerical condition on $n$ is necessary and sufficient for existence of an STS.
In contrast, all the affine planes known are for $k$ being a prime power, but a theorem saying that these are the only possibilites is very much out of reach now.

Comment: Maybe ‘most values’ is a bit unfair. If k is constant or very slowly growing with n, the problem is solved, by Wilson; much more recent work of Keevash and of Glock, Kühn, Lo and Osthus deals with the same if the graph decomposed is typical, and with the hypergraph versions. These results are all more or less algorithmic.

Comment: well, these are asymptotic results, for fixed $k$, and $n$ big enough, there will be an example, assuming the easy to get numeric restrictions on $n$ w.r.t. $k$. One can argue that it's still open for most cases...

Comment: The case that I'm really interested in is when k and n are both large, to be specific let's say n=1000, k=100. (I should also mention that I'm even interested in an algorithm that can reach a maximal number of cliques)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "maximal number of cliques". In a (n,k,1)-BIBD you must have exactly one block through the any pair of points, so the number of blocks is determined by n and k, you don't have any freedom here.

Comment: Well, what I mean is an algorithm that can find as many blocks of size k from the n points that limits any pair of points to be at most in one block. In other words, not all pairs necessarily need to be in a block, I just wanna maximize the number of blocks.

In the case where ($n=k^2$) where k is a prime power, the maximal solution is indeed the affine plane. However, for arbitrary values of large n and k, I'm not able to find a proper solution.